# how to make ellipse in java swing JPanel TitledBorder?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

[image]
how to draw this in java swing TitledBorder or any other panel ?
i tried the following code and didn't work, kept drawing half ellipse and the other half was cut.

```
@Override
public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width,
        int height) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;      
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    FontMetrics m = c.getFontMetrics(getTitleFont());

    Ellipse2D shape = new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Float(2, -20,m.stringWidth(title)+10, m.getHeight()+40);


    g2.fill(shape);
    g2.draw(shape);
    super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);


}
```

Comment: The answer to your problem involves setting the right `Insets` - updating the top inset for the extra space necessary to paint your `RoundedRectangle`

Comment: i think i tried, can you show me example which should work ?